# How to make jquery terminal cursor a block, but an underscore?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-terminal

How can I change the jquery terminal cursor so it can be like in the picture here: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfUvz.png). I have tried messing with the css, and I was able to change the shape a bit using `.cmd` in css but it wouldnt change the thickness and height making it noneffective.

I do know there is a variable called: `--animation: terminal-bar` that you can add to the terminal's css but im not sure if there is one that can make it an underscore.

Comment: class cmd-cursor or cmd-blink

Comment: @SKJ I have tried editing the .cmd-cursor and the .cmd-blink but for some reason its not changing for me when adding things like ```height``` and ```width``` properties, and I think there are some variables for them but trying ```--height``` or ```--size``` or ```--width``` still doesnt work.

Comment: Alright thanks, is there any way to change the thickness of it? I cant find in the documentation where I can change it, ive tried ```height``` and ```--height``` already but doesnt change

Comment: No, there is no way to change the thickness. I think that I should add a way to customize it. The same as underscore. Right now you can open the CSS file and find `@keyframes terminal-bar` and the prefixed versions and change the box-shadow. You should be able to change the thickness.

Comment: Here is example how to add `--bar-thickness` variable to custom animation https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/RwvXaRG?editors=0100

Comment: @jcubic alright thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://terminal.jcubic.pl/api_reference.php#style) it says

> To change font size of the terminal you can use this code:

```
toggle highlight .terminal, .cmd, .terminal .terminal-output div div, .cmd .prompt {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 24px; 
}
```

> Or from version 1.0.0 (and if you don't care about IE or Edge) you can simplify the code using --size css variables
> like this:

```
toggle highlight .terminal {   
   --size: 2;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('body').terminal(
  function(command, term) {
    if (command == 'test') {
      term.echo("you just typed 'test'");
    } else {
      term.echo('unknown command');
    }
  }, {
    prompt: 'user@host:~ $ ',
    greetings: false
  }
);
```

```css
.terminal {
  --background: black;
  --color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.99);
  --size: 1.3;
  --animation: terminal-underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.terminal/2.37.1/js/jquery.terminal.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.terminal/2.37.1/css/jquery.terminal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```